# How to get the program and feature in the lua table

Tags: lua

from the below

Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features

Need the List view in the Lua table

Suppose the Name of the Program installed , its version and size etc.

Issue is Lua seems to doesn't takes two argument  like two dimension array

Using Lua table you can store List of string

But how to store a two dimension array ?

Comment: Pretty please, with sugar on top, don't capitalize Lua.

Comment: No offense to the author, but there's a lot more wrong with this than capitalizing Lua, :P, I had trouble understanding your question so I tried to explain best I could what I thought you were asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
table = {}

for i = 1, 10 do
   table[i] = {}
   for j = 1, 10
      table[i][j] = i+j
   end
end
```

A multidimensional array in Lua is simply multiple tables in another :), one for each row/col.

Oh and another option is faking a multidimensional array through some simple arithmatic, something like: table[x+rowlen*y]